# How to calculate the sum of the list using stream?

Tags: java

I have a `List<Integer>` like `{ 1, 2, 3 ,4, 5 }`, I'd like to get the result like `12345`.

How to do this using Java8 streams *or* any smart way?

`List` consists of single digit non-negative integers.

I could definitely do like `1*10000+ 2 * 1000 + 3*100 + 4*10 + 5`, but it is quite tedious.

Comment: How would you want to handle numbers in the array with more than one digit? Or negative numbers? Or is the input constrained to be single-digit non-negative numbers?

Comment: single digit, non negative

Comment: [edit] the question to specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`IntStream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#reduce-int-java.util.function.IntBinaryOperator-):

```
int n = IntStream.of(array).reduce(0, (a,b) -> 10*a + b)
```

This is effectively the same as:

```
int n = 0;
for (int b : array) {
  n = 10 * n + b;
}
```

Personally, I would opt for the latter in the absence of other constraints, since it is much simpler code, doesn't involve the relatively heavyweight streams framework, easier to debug etc.

Comment: I like it, I was thinking "but there's not `zipWithIndex`" - this is neat.

Comment: @BoristheSpider re your comment on another answer that didn't use streams: OP says "streams or any smart way".

Comment: Not sure it classified as that.

Answer (score 1):

This one is by *not using streams* but a ***possible* way** using regex:

```
Integer.parseInt(Arrays.toString(nums).replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
```

Comment: "probable smart" it's concise, not smart.

Comment: This is one of those neat but inefficient one liners, good for code golf and the such - bad for anything else.

Comment: @AndyTurner ty for pointing out. I changed it to possible which seems more apt.

Comment: Note that you can handle the "multi digit" case that this handles by modifying the lambda: `(a,b) -> { int bCopy = b; do { a *= 10; } while ((bCopy /= 10) != 0); return a + b`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also get to the same result using:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int size = ints.size();
double res = IntStream.range(1, size + 1)
        .mapToDouble(i -> ints.get(i - 1) * Math.pow(10, size - i))
        .sum();
```

That's just adding the sum of each `digit*(10^digit_position_from_right)`, with `digit_position_from_right` starting at zero.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Didn't, the question says "I have a list"... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Probably, one of the most pragmatic ideas would be to treat numbers as strings and then parse them at the end:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
Long result = list.stream()
  .map(Object::toString)
  .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
    Collectors.joining(), Long::parseLong));
```

Comment: Not amazingly efficient, integer ops are much after than converting to `String`, concating, then parsing back.

Answer (score 0):

The result can be achieved using following method:

```
List<Integer> nums = Arrays.asList(1, 2,3,4);
String s = "";
for (Integer x : nums) {
     s += x.toString();
}
Integer FinalNum = Integer.parseInt(s);
```